# Include two different package Directories during unlocked package creation

Tags: managed-package, package, unlocked-package, 2gp

I am having different set of LWC components some under force-app and some under common folder. My sxdf-project.json is

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [{
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Finance",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
        },
        {
            "path": "common",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "49.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "Finance": "0Ho2w0000004CpQCAU",
       
    }
}
```

when I tried to create 2GP unlocked package version with the below command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "Finance" --installationkeybypass --wait 20 --path "force-app,common"
```

I am getting below error

```
The --path (-d) value [force-app,common], doesn’t match the path value in any packageDirectories specified in sfdx-project.json
```

Am I missing someting or
Can't we include two folders during version creation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. Each package may only be one directory. From your question, it appears you want two packages, with the force-app package depending on the common package.

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Finance",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [{ "package": "Common@0.1.0.1" }]
        },
        {
            "path": "common",
            "default": false,
            "package": "Common",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "49.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "Finance": "0Ho2w0000004CpQCAU",
        "Common": "<to-be-created>"
    }
}
```

Future packages can then also depend on the common package as well.

Comment: whether its allowed to create unlocked package for "common" and reference it to "force-app" which I am trying as Managed package?

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner No, you'd need two managed packages.